# Why is Eclipse Europa constantly crashing?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tomcat

I'm currently battling with Eclipse Europa to get it to play ball with an SVN repository and a Tomcat project. Everytime it bails out, I get the following:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/java/latest/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-jar /users/0600083h/Level 3/TeamProject/eclipse/plugins
/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.1.R33x_v20080118.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /users/0600083h/Level 3/TeamProject/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /users/0600083h/Level 3/TeamProject/eclipse/pluginS/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.3.R33x_v20080118/eclipse_1023.so
-startup /users/0600083h/Level 3/TeamProject/eclipse/plugins    /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.1.R33x_v20080118.jar
-exitdata 3ea8013
-vm /usr/java/latest/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-jar /users/0600083h/Level 3/TeamProject/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.1.R33x_v20080118.jar
```

It seems to happen intermittently - when starting the server, when connecting or committing to the repo. I can't suss out a cause, and having it crash every 2 minutes if no good...

Any suggestions for how to rectify this?

Comment: May be an issue with a SVN 32 bit used with a eclipse-jdk 64 bits?

Comment: Do Ganymede (3.4) or Galileo (3.5) exhibit the same problems?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test with 3.4/.5 - limited by the university to Europe...

I'll double check the version of SVN i'm using. Appreciate the responses!

Comment: Just for info, I experienced Eclipse sudden deaths with vers. 3.3 all the way to 3.5 . So at least in my case there was no version dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the 'other' SVN client, depending on which one you use. I currently use subversive having previously used subclipse. Both worked well for me when I used Europa.

- [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)
- [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)

Not a fix/solution for your problem, but maybe something to try.

Answer (score 0):

Doing SVN is... stressful to Eclipse, for lack of a more precise description. There are (at least) two different SVN connectors: One is java-based and not highly efficient, so it causes a bunch of memory/GC thrashing. The other is native, with all the dangers that can arise from that.

But I can't claim a direct connection.

My Eclipse (Europa, and later Galileo) used to crash intermittently too. This improved when I got a new Linux installed on my box.

Comment: I'm going to try from scratch setting up each component one by one - vanilla Eclipse, Subversion, Tomcat... see how we go. Incredibly frustrating though :)

Comment: I hear you. I was crawling up the walls. Because it was an intermittent problem, our admins refused to even look at it. I built myself scripts to delete lockfiles and other stuff that got corrupted when Eclipse died in mid-session. The good news is, on a clean, well set up machine, Eclipse Just Works (TM).

Comment: Have you checked the .log file?

Comment: Ouch - I think the trade off in time is worth it in the long run.

Greg - have checked, though it's all mysterious to me. SIGSEV error? Can post them up online somewhere if you think you can make head or tail of it..

Comment: from the cmd line

# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b33d8c3325a, pid=6346, tid=1109207360
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x1f125a]